# Derby database BOOLEAN not recognized after create

Tags: sql, database, eclipse, derby, embedded-database

I am trying to create and use and embedded database in Eclipse. So this is why I am using Derby.

I am creating a table named "users2" (because I want to test things on it). When I create a SQL script and having "BOOLEAN" field it succeed. And then it does not recognize it and leads to errors.

[All steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSA2I.png)

Comment: Can you use INT instead?  Or smallint, tinyint, etc

Comment: When I use TINYINT(1) it is giving me error for "(1)". Any suggestions ? And if I use SMALLINT, how I am going to limit it to just 2 choices ?

Comment: Tinyint should have a value of 1 or 0...Not "(1)"

Comment: I just tried, and: TYPE 'TINYINT' does not exist.

Comment: Have you got a list of valid data types?  That will have what you need

Comment: https://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/ref/crefsqlj31068.html

Comment: It seems that perhaps your Interface may not be fully compatible with your database...  What version are you running?  (NOT of your database, of the IDE you are using to EDIT the table)

Comment: You can test this by scripting an INSERT statement with your BOOLEAN field...If NO error - then the IDE (front end) is the problem

Comment: I am in "Database Development" perspective. I am not using this db, I am trying to create it first. I think I found my mistake. When I create the connection, I am passing a jar with Derby drivers of version 10.14..., but before it, when I am selecting it it says "System version 10.2" [CHECK THIS](https://ibb.co/nhiY7b) . What do you think ?

Comment: Perhaps try in a database that matches you system version...

Comment: No I am really pissed off, I am starting to learn H2 database now. I have a task in which i need to use embedded DB, so all day I am trying with this Derby and I will switch to H2 :)

Comment: Derby 10.2 is **ancient**, if you can figure out how to get the correct JDBC driver configured for your Eclipse you will have a **much** better experience with Derby.